# What is the difference between "eval" and "source /dev/stdin"?

Tags: bash, command-line

Between the following alternatives...

1. with `eval`.

   ```
   comd="ls"
   eval "$comd"
   ```
2. with `source /dev/stdin`

   ```
   printf "ls" | source /dev/stdin
   ```
3. with `source /dev/stdin` and `( )` or `{ }`

   ```
   ( printf "ls" ) | source /dev/stdin
   { printf "ls"; } | source /dev/stdin
   ```

   (When we run `printf` in `{ }`, is there any benefit other than not using subshell?)

   - What is the difference between them?
   - Which is preferred?
   - Which is the preferred way to run commands? `()` or `{}`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either approach. What are you actually trying to *do*, that you think you need to execute arbitrary code submitted by a user?

Comment: I also though they were executing arbitrary user input (as it is), until I read the question. But may be you are predicting that they will.

Answer (score 33):

> What is the difference between the ways?

From `man bash`:

```
eval [arg ...]
              The  args  are read and concatenated together into a single com‐
              mand.  This command is then read and executed by the shell,  and
              its  exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are
              no args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.

source filename [arguments]
              Read and execute commands from filename  in  the  current  shell
              environment  and return the exit status of the last command exe‐
              cuted from filename.  If filename does not contain a slash, file
              names  in  PATH  are used to find the directory containing file‐
              name.  The file searched for in PATH  need  not  be  executable.
              When  bash  is  not  in  posix  mode,  the  current directory is
              searched if no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath  option
              to  the  shopt  builtin  command  is turned off, the PATH is not
              searched.  If any arguments are supplied, they become the  posi‐
              tional  parameters  when  filename  is  executed.  Otherwise the
              positional parameters are unchanged.  The return status  is  the
              status  of  the  last  command exited within the script (0 if no
              commands are executed), and false if filename is  not  found  or
              cannot be read.
```

There are no differences between the two ways.

There is only one note: `eval` concatenated all of its arguments, which is then run as a single command. `source` reads the contents of a file and executes them. `eval` can only build commands from its arguments, not `stdin`. So you can not do this:

```
printf "ls" | eval
```

> Which is more preferred?

Your example provides the same result, but the purpose of `eval` and `source` is different. `source` is usually used for providing a library for other scripts, while `eval` is used only to evaluate commands. `eval` should be avoided if possible, because there is no guarantee that the `eval`'ed string is clean; sanity checks must be done, using `subshell`.

> If we run some commands in `()` or `{}`, which is more preferred?

When sequences of commands are run inside curly braces `{ }`, all commands are run in the **current shell**, instead of a **subshell** (which is the case if you run inside parentheses (see bash [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping))).

Using `subshell ( )` uses more resources, but the current environment is not affected. Using `{ }` runs all the commands in the current shell, so the environment is affected. Which to choose depends on your purpose.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Of course, you cannot replace `eval` by `source`. I guess the question is: Is `eval "$cmd"` equivalent to `echo "$cmd" | source /dev/stdin`. My current opinion is: yes.

Comment: @cuonglm ... that has to be the most concise answer on any Stack-xxx site I've seen to date. :-)

Answer (score 11):

The main difference is that 2nd and 3rd form are using a pipe, which will force bash to run the "source" command in a subshell (unless lastpipe is set, only available in bash 4.2+), which will make it pretty much equivalent to:

```
printf "ls" | bash
```

The consequences are that any environment variables set by your code will be lost, so this will not work as expected:

```
printf "abc=2" | source /dev/stdin
```

To run the commands in current shell, you can use process substitution:

```
source <(printf "abc=2")
```

You can put more commands inside parenthesis using semicolon as usual.

If you eliminate the pipe this way, I believe there is no difference between using "eval" and "source".
You should prefer the one that is simpler to use in your particular case:

- if you already have commands to run in variable, use "eval"
- if you have them in a file or getting them from external command, use "source"

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to the answers already given:

A `source` equivalent to ...

```
comd="ls"
eval "$comd"
```

... is ...

```
source <(printf ls)
```

In case of `ls` there is no significant difference.

But in case of a command that is intended to **affect your current environment** (what you usually intend when using `source`) this variant would do it (as your 1st solution with `eval` also would) while your 2nd approach just affects the environment of a subshell that won't be available after executing your line of code.

Comment: One being standard and the other one not being standard I'd say is a pretty big difference.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "standard"?

Comment: Sorry. My initial thought, before I noticed the `bash` tag, was that the variation with `eval` obviously was standard and the other wasn't, as it used non-POSIX `source`.  You then proposed using another non-POSIX feature, the process substitution.  Personally, I would say that if there is an equivalent standard way of doing something, that is to be preferred due to portability, while the `bash`-only variations may be usable in `bash` scripts that never need to be ported to other systems or shells. Do take my comment lightly as I didn't initially spot that this was about `bash` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

There's one important distinction that hasn't been made yet!

```
❯ echo return | . /dev/stdin

❯ echo return | eval "$(cat -)"
sh: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

That is - `return` only works when sourcing a script.

Depending on the contents and intention of your script, it likely won't matter which you choose, but I figured this difference is worth pointing out.

---

In the above I pipe to `eval` instead of just an `eval return` for two reasons:

1. Just to demonstrate it's possible to pipe into `eval`.
2. For consistency so both `source` and `eval` can run within a subshell (the pipe).

   For example, if we tried something like:

   ```
   ❯ echo a=1 | . /dev/stdin; echo $a
   ❯ echo a=1 | eval "$(cat -)"; echo $a
   ```

   We'll find `1` isn't printed since it wasn't evaluated within our current environment. We'd have to do the following instead to get the `1` to print:

   ```
   ❯ echo a=1 | { . /dev/stdin; echo $a; }
   ❯ echo a=1 | { eval "$(cat -)"; echo $a; }
   ```