# Sourcing alias fails - No such file or directory

Tags: bash, alias

I have a large number of shell scripts in a deep directory tree with varying versions. To simplify using these I added a function to create an alias (selected via command line option):

```
function make_alias {
    local CMD NAME
    NAME=$( basename ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} )
    CMD=$( realpath ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} )
    echo "alias $NAME=\"$CMD\""
    exit 0
}
```

If I run this, it generates a valid alias command on stdout, e.g.

```
$ ./myscript -a
alias myscript="/home/symcbean/library/tools/webserver/myscript"
```

I can cut and paste this, it works.

However if I try to source the output in my current shell I get an error:

```
$ source $(./myscript -a)
-bash: alias: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

(Using bash 5.1.16 on Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: `source` expects a filename, but you're giving it a string `alias ...` - you could possibly use a *process substitution* `source <(./myscript -a)` in place of the command substitution or maybe `eval` in place of `source` (although I'm not sure if either option is particularly sanitary). See also [What is the difference between "eval" and "source /dev/stdin"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123063/what-is-the-difference-between-eval-and-source-dev-stdin)

Comment: Doh - Not enough coffee. Yes, `source` expects a file - I need eval.

Answer (score 1):

```
source $(./myscript -a)
```

That can't work. `source` is meant to read the source code of another shell script file, and execute it in the current shell. You could `eval $(./myscript -a)`, that would work, but hm, that's a very awkward use case for aliases.

I'd honestly just place a symlink to your script in a directory under /var/run and add that to the path (if not already part of it):

```bash
function make_alias {
  local executable
  local binpath

  executable=$0
  binpath="/var/run/${UID}/shortcuts"

  mkdir -p "${binpath}"
  # next 3 lines adapted from https://superuser.com/a/39995/563936
  if [[ ":$PATH:" != *":${binpath}:"* ]]; then
    PATH="${PATH:+"$PATH:"}${binpath}"
  fi

  # Place symlink in /var/run sudirectory
  ln -s "$(realpath "${executable}")" "${binpath}/$(basename "${executable}")"
}
```

Personally, I find that much more elegant than cluttering your shell with numerous aliases: by picking the position in `$PATH`, you can define priorities, i.e. no chance of accidentally hiding important system commands, things like `type` and `which` still work as intended, it's easy to get an overview of which shortcuts you made already (by looking into said directory), and shortcuts transport between multiple shells without having to be set up in every single one (as long as the `$binpath` is in the `$PATH` of both)…